# Yii Tabular Input

Tags: php, yii, tabular

I want to add multiple records from a form into a table.

I have tried to understand and follow this guide and failed

[Yii tabular input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table)

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

My code does not save.

I have a comment in my controller code written **A**, here with the `isset()` function added

this part of the code will not run.

```
if(isset($_POST['MultiPart2'][$i]))
```

But when I removed the isset() function I get the error **Undefined offset: 0**

This means this code

```
$_POST['MultiPart2'][$i]
```

Is not working.

What should I do?

Here is the var_dump of my post

```
$_POST['MultiPart2']

array(2) {
   ["[0"]=>
   array(3) {
     ["'name'"]=>
     string(3) "Vic"
     ["'age'"]=>
     string(2) "25"
     ["'sex'"]=>
     string(1) "m"
   }
  ["[1"]=>
  array(3) {
     ["'name'"]=>
     string(3) "Vic"
     ["'age'"]=>
     string(2) "25"
     ["'sex'"]=>
     string(1) "m"
   }
}
```

Here is my controller code

```
 public function actionCreate()
 {

    //insert multiple instances of model into array
    $model=array();
    for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) { 
        $model[]=new MultiPart2;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['MultiPart2']))
    {   
        foreach ($model as $i => $model) {

            if(isset($_POST['MultiPart2'][$i]))
             // A
            //with isset() the following code does not run
            {       

                $model->attributes=$_POST['MultiPart2'][$i];
                if($model->save())
                    echo "Saved";
            }
        }
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

And here is my view code

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'multi-part2-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <?php 
    foreach ($model as $i => $model) {
            ?>

                <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model,"[$i][name]",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"Vic")); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'age'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model,"[$i][age]",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"5")); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model,'age'); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'sex'); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->textField($model,"[$i][sex]",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"m")); ?>
                    <?php echo $form->error($model,'sex'); ?>
                </div> 
                <hr>
            <?php
        }

     ?>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Here is the generated HTML

```
<form id="multi-part2-form" action="/sam.com/system/index.php?r=multiPart2/create"      method="post">
    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>



<div class="row">
 <label for="MultiPart2_name"   class="required">Name <span class="required">*</span>   </label>                           
 <input size="60" maxlength="100"   value="Vic" name="MultiPart2[[0][name]]" id="MultiPart2__0_name" type="text" />                     

</div>

<div class="row">
<label for="MultiPart2_age" class="required">Age <span class="required">*</span></label>                        
<input size="60" maxlength="100" value="5" name="MultiPart2[[0][age]]" id="MultiPart2__0_age" type="text" />                                            

</div>

<div class="row">
<label for="MultiPart2_sex" class="required">Sex <span class="required">*</span></label>                        
<input size="60" maxlength="100" value="m" name="MultiPart2[[0][sex]]" id="MultiPart2__0_sex" type="text" />                                              
</div> 

<hr>

<div class="row">
<label for="MultiPart2_name" class="required">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>                      
<input size="60" maxlength="100" value="Vic" name="MultiPart2[[1][name]]" id="MultiPart2__1_name" type="text" />                        

</div>

<div class="row">

<label for="MultiPart2_age" class="required">Age <span class="required">*</span></label>                          
<input size="60" maxlength="100" value="5" name="MultiPart2[[1][age]]" id="MultiPart2__1_age" type="text" />                                            
</div>

<div class="row">
<label for="MultiPart2_sex" class="required">Sex <span class="required">*</span></label>                        
<input size="60" maxlength="100" value="m" name="MultiPart2[[1][sex]]" id="MultiPart2__1_sex" type="text" />                                             
</div> 

<hr>

<div class="row buttons">
<input type="submit" name="yt0" value="Create" />   </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change generation of text inputs to:

```
     <?php echo $form->textField($model,"[$i]name",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"Vic")); ?>
                //...
     <?php echo $form->textField($model,"[$i]age",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"5")); ?>
                //..
     <?php echo $form->textField($model,"[$i]sex",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"m")); ?>
```

Its  wrap input name in double qoutes `"` ( now `$i` doesnt interpreted as varialble - because it in sinqle qoutes).

Also try change like:

```
 $model=array();
for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) { 
    $model[$i]=new MultiPart2;
}

if(isset($_POST['MultiPart2']))
{   

    foreach ($model as $i=>$mod) {

        if(isset($_POST['MultiPart2'][$i]))
         // A
        //with isset() the following code does not run
        {       

            $mod->attributes=$_POST['MultiPart2'][$i];
            if($mod->save())
                echo "Saved";
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT_2_** Change also view code to (same mistake with name):

```
    foreach ($model as $i => $mod) {
        ?>

            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($mod,'name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->activeTextField($mod,"[$i]name",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"Vic")); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($mod,'name'); ?>
            </div>
            //... other inputs
```

Or try like:

```
        foreach ($model as $i => $mod) {
        ?>

            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($mod,'name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField("MultiPart2[$id]['name']",$mod['name'],array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"Vic")); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($mod,'name'); ?>
            </div>



            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($mod,'age'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField("MultiPart2[$id]['age']",$mod['age'],array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"Vic")); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($mod,'age'); ?>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($mod,'sex'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField("MultiPart2[$id]['sex']",$mod['sex'],array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"Vic")); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($mod,'sex'); ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: After doing what you suggested and I did a var dump, and I can see all the data, But still I get an offset error...

Comment: update again. Try. I found error. You iterate same varialbles. Advice: for multiple entities use name as `$models` ( not `$model`). Now you do foreach like `$model as $model` - its not properly.

Comment: when i var dump my post it displays what is inside. But when I try vardump like this `var_dump($_POST['MultiPart2'][0]);` it brings the offset error.

Comment: Made the changes you have sugested. But I still get an undefined offset: 0 when I either var dump `var_dump($_POST['MultiPart2'][0]);` or try to access `$mod->attributes=$_POST['MultiPart2'][$i];` and when i have the isset() function, it does not run the code after it.

Comment: @voodoo417 +1 for your continuous try and also for finding most of the issues :-)

Comment: @voodoo417 added the HTML for the whole form

Comment: @Victor Njoroge Problem that Yii generate name as  `MultiPart2[[0][name]]` ? You changed code in `view` in loop `foreach ($model as $i => $mod) {` and in `<?php echo $form->textField($mod,"[$i]name"` ?

Comment: updated answer. Change `textField` to `activeTextField` in `view`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your view code as below:

Remove `''`  around name in `"[$i]['name']"` - and in all fields also

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,"[$i][name]",array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100, "value"=>"Vic")); ?>
```

And also change the variable name in foreach as Voodoo417 said.

```
foreach ($model as $i => $mod) {
```

Comment: I have done that but nothing has changed. I still get the offest error or the the code for saving is jumped if I add the isset() function. Any more ideas...

Comment: @voodoo417 Thx. I didn't notice the iterated same variable. You found it first. So i mentioned your name in my edit.

Comment: he has same mistake in `view` with iteration : `$model as $i=>$model` :)